# Python: Parsing a variety of different text file emails

Tags: python, regex, email, text-files

These are 3 snippets from 3 different emails:

```
1)
Subject: NEFS 11 and 12 fish for lease

Greetings,

NEFS 11 has the following fish for lease:
up to 4,000 lbs live wt GOM cod @ 1.40 lbs
NEFS 12 has the following fish for lease:
2,000 lbs American plaice @ .45 lbs

Please let me know if you're interested in either,


2)
Subject: NEFS 11 fish for lease

2,000 lbs Grey sole @ 1.20 or best offer
1,000 lbs dabs @ .55 or best offer

thanks,


3)
Subject: NEFS 11 fish for lease

-GOM Cod up to 5,000 lbs (live wt) @ 1.40 lbs
-American Plaice 2,000 lbs      .60 lbs or best offer
```

My question is: what is the most efficient way to go about parsing out the Sector (NEFS 11, 12), the Species (GOM cod, Grey sole), the Pounds (4,000 lbs, 2,000lbs), and the Price (1.40/lb, 0.55/lb) information from these emails?

My first thought was to use RegEx. But I am not sure that is the best method because my code currently captures too much information; for example, when I go to grab the Weight data I end up grabbing the Price data as well because both are adjacent to "lbs". And when I try to capture the Sector data I capture the entire Subject line.

Here is a piece of my code used to parse the Species data out of the emails:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        sector_result = []
        pattern = re.compile("Available Quota | CC Yellowtail Flounder | GOM Yellowtail Flounder | GB Cod East | GB Cod West | GB Haddock East | GB Haddock West | GB Winter Flounder | GB Yellowtail Flounder | GOM Cod | GOM Haddock | GOM Winter Flounder | Plaice | Pollock | Redfish | SNE Winter Flounder | ME Winter Flounder | SNE Yellowtail Flounder | ME Yellowtail Flounder | White Hake | Witch Flounder", re.IGNORECASE)
        for linenum, line in enumerate(f):
            if pattern.search(line) != None:
                sector_result.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
                for linenum, line in sector_result:
                    print ("Fish Species:", line)
```

I search for all possible species that could be found in the emails and ideally (for example 3) I would produce: "Fish Species: GOM Cod, American Plaice" but what gets produced is `Fish Species: -American Plaice 2,000 lbs      .60 lbs or best offer`.

I am not an expert on using RegEx so I would appreciate either help modifying my RegEx code or advice on another method I should use to parse these, and many more, emails. Thank you.

Additional Email:

```
NEFS 5 has the following fish available for lease/trade:

GB EAST cod: 954 lbs @ $0.83
GB EAST cod: 1,046 lbs to trade for 1,830 lbs GB WEST cod
GB blackback: 30,000 lbs @ $0.07
GOM blackback: 800 lbs @ $0.03
white hake: 6,322 lbs @ $0.13
pollock: 22,000 lbs @ $0.015
redfish: 14,000 lbs @ $0.015
GB yt: 1,873 lbs @ $1.13
GB yt: 5,127 lbs to trade for 10,254 lbs SNE yt
```

Comment: your question seems to want more information than your ideal solution for example 3, what exactly would you want the output to be?

Comment: further, if there is absolutely no form of standardization among the emails, you are looking at a machine learning problem as opposed to regex

Comment: I said above that for Email #3 ideally the output would simply be: `Fish Species: GOM Cod, American Plaice` . Further, you're correct there is no standardization, these emails are each sent individually by humans; does that mean there exists no possible way to parse the desired data out of 100's of these emails?

Comment: to avoid using machine learning, I think your best bet would be to identify the most common ways the information is presented and use regex on those. You would then be able to get a majority of the data, but not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting just the different fish types:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    pattern = re.compile(r"Available Quota|CC Yellowtail Flounder|GOM Yellowtail Flounder|GB Cod East|GB Cod West|GB Haddock East|GB Haddock West|GB Winter Flounder|GB Yellowtail Flounder|GOM Cod|GOM Haddock|GOM Winter Flounder|Plaice|Pollock|Redfish|SNE Winter Flounder|ME Winter Flounder|SNE Yellowtail Flounder|ME Yellowtail Flounder|White Hake|Witch Flounder", re.IGNORECASE)
    email = f.read()
    fish_types = pattern.findall(email)
    if fish_types:
        print("Fish Species:", " ".join(fish_types))
```

Comment: That works almost perfectly and I think I know why it isn't perfect. It only printed `Fish Species: Plaice` did it not recognize the "GOM Cod" and "American" because those are adjacent to dash marks in the email? Like "-GOM Cod" as opposed to "GOM Cod"

Comment: Oh it's likely because of the spaces in the regex. Let me fix that. The regex was trying to match ' GOM Cod ' as opposed to just 'GOM Cod'

Comment: Ohhh ok that makes sense. So I really don't want to inundate you with questions but just quickly: up until now when I would try to capture the pounds amount, for example, I would use RegEx to search for "pounds|lbs", and then I would get hung up....I had previously been capturing the entire line but that's obviously too much extra stuff. I am aware of non-capturing groups but not fully aware of if that could be used here. Is there a way to capture a number the directly precedes a RegEx match? Such is the case with "2,000 lbs" for example?

Comment: If you are pretty confident that the weights will look as they do, it may be simpler to use `re.compile(r'\d+,\d+')` which will identify all strings that contain a number then comma then number.

Comment: Wow that does succeed in capturing the correct 5,000 and 2,000 amounts. So should the same method be used for capturing the prices? Except replacing the comma with a period for the "1.20 lb" and "0.55 lb" values?

Comment: I would do this `re.compile(r'(\d+)?\.\d+')`

Comment: That didn't work :( it only printed "1" for some reason. I don't want to keep you here though if you need to go back to your own work, I know it's my project not yours. Or if you'd like to help me solve this difficult mess we could relocate this discussion to chat?

Comment: also this should work. `re.compile(r'(?:\d+)?\.\d+')`

Comment: Turns out I can't actually move to a chat because my reputation is too low. But that compile worked!! Basically what I'm gathering is, apart from learning how to implement machine learning, I need to THOROUGHLY learn RegEx in order to successfully parse these 100's of emails, is that accurate? Your understanding of RegEx seems to be able to solve any problem a txt file throws at you

Comment: well, regex will help you to an extent, but if someone misspells a fish or formats their weights/prices differently, regex won't help you.  I suggest using a regex to hit a majority of emails and then manually get the data from the ones that dont work with regex

Comment: That is sort of what I had in mind when I started this project. Thanks for all the help though and for the advice, I appreciate it so much that you made a genuine effort to help me out.

Comment: Hey. I had one more quick question, I hope you don't mind me asking you directly. But I added one more example email above, and in this one the dollar amounts do have a $ before them so the code fails to recognize them....is there a way to use an if loop with RegEx? Like "if dollar sign exists, capture number on either side of decimal point directly after. If not, capture numbers on either side of decimal point like before"?  Or would a smarter method be to write an entire new block of code after the one I currently have written for the prices without $ signs?

Comment: The `?` allows for a character to either appear once or not at all. You could probably add `$?` to the front of the regex you were using to do what you are looking for.